# Cannot see PostgreSQL in Kubernetes Through a Browser

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I am testing a PostgreSQL configuration in kubernetes.

Windows 11
HyperV
Minikube

Everything works (or seems to work) fine
I can connect to the dabase via

```
kubectl exec -it pod/postgres-0 -- bash
bash-5.1$ psql --username=$POSTGRES_USER -W --host=localhost --port=5432 --dbname=pg_test
Password:
psql (13.6)
Type "help" for help.

pg_test=#
```

I cam also view the database through DBeaver.

But when I try to connect from any browser,
localhost:5432
I get errors such as :

```
firefox canot connect,
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I have no proxy

when I try

```
kubectl port-forward service/postgres-service 5432:5432
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:5432 -> 5432
Forwarding from [::1]:5432 -> 5432
Handling connection for 5432
Handling connection for 5432
... this line repeats indefinitely for connections attempt
Handling connection for 5432
Handling connection for 5432
...
```

Here is my YAML config file

...

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  db: pg_test
  user: admin
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-config

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  serviceName: "postgres"
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      env: prod
      domain: infrastructure
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        env: prod
        domain: infrastructure
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 20
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 70
        fsGroup: 70
      containers:
      - name: kubia-postgres
        image: postgres:13-alpine
        env:
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: admin
          # valueFrom:
          #   secretKeyRef:
          #     name: postgres-secret
          #     key: password
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          value: admin
          # valueFrom:
          #   configMapKeyRef:
          #     name: postgres-config
          #     key: user
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: postgres-config
              key: db
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: postgres-test-volume
          mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "64Mi"
            cpu: "250m"
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
      volumes:
      - name: postgres-test-volume
        emptyDir: {}

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres-service
  labels:
    env: prod
    domain: infrastructure
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5432
    targetPort: 5432
    protocol: TCP
    name: pgsql
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    env: prod
    domain: infrastructure
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you connect with `psql` if you don't use kubectl to tunnel into the machine first, but just use it from the container host's console?

Comment: Yes, I can connect with psql and also DBeaver

Comment: PostgreSQL is a database server, not a web server.  What you are doing should return an error, although not that particular error.  What are you trying to do?  What do you hope to accomplish by pointing a http client at something which is not a http server?

Comment: When connecting with psql without kubectl, what are the options you give it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access your Postgres instance using a web browser, you need to deploy and configure something like [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't opened the service to the internet. You were only tunneling the port to you localhost. To do so you well need one of these Kubernetes services:

- Port forwarding
- Nodeport: Maps a port to your hosts port.
- ClusterIP: It gives your service an internal Ip to be refered to in-cluster.
- LoadBalancer: Assigns an Ip or a cloud providers load balancers to the service effectively making it available to external traffic.

Since you are using Minikube, you should try a LoadBalancer or a ClusterIP.
By the way, you are creating a service without a type and you are not giving it an ip.

The important parts in a service for it to work on development are the selector labels, port and type.

[Exposing an IP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/) || [Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/)